# Why my method found expression 4 times instead single result?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I checked source of page and there is no more searched text than 2 (one is found as link and other is found in the short description). So I don't really know why my method returns 4 results :/

This is the code:

```
public int isTextPresent(String text) {
    List<WebElement> foundElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + text + "')]]"));
    return foundElements.size();
}
```

Do you have some idea what is wrong with this code/xpath ?

Comment: You tried searching with the same xpath?

Comment: What is that `text`, what is the page/HTML? How could we know what's wrong with your code without this info?

Comment: @Andersson I've added info.

Comment: when opening the page with chrome and test the xpath you provide, there are two results showing. If you provide more code, it might be possible to identify the problem

Comment: I can see 2 results only... Maybe try to make your XPath more specific `//a[contains(.,'" + text + "')]` or you can search by partialLinkText: `By.partialLinkText(text)` to get only visible links with required text

Comment: @Andersson, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've changed method slightly and it works properly now :)

```
public int isTextPresent(String text) {
    List<WebElement> fe = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText(text));
    return fe.size();
}
```